# Abort while deleting inherited object without using virtual destructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class a
{
public : ~a() { cout << "a"; };
};
class b :virtual public a
{
public : ~b() { cout << "b"; };
};
```

in this code when i tried make something like that :

```
a* p = new b;
delete p;
```

give me an error (abort),although if i remove virtual inheritance it worked.
I know it's not true to make some thing like that without virtual destructor ,
but why this error appear only when i used virtual inheritance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delete, whether the inheritance is virtual, or not, is undefined behavior in either case.

The superclass must have a virtual destructor, in order to be able to execute a delete using a pointer to the superclass.

Just because one variation of your code works on your platform, doesn't mean that either variation is valid. It is not. Change your destructor to a virtual destructor, and this should work whether or not the inheritance it virtual, or not.